# Logic App - HTTP POST/Upsert data in smaller amount

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to GET a large amount of data from Service Now → Change some JSON body of it in Logic App → and Upsert it to SAP.

Here's the logic I have applied in my Logic App:

[image]

HTTP to GET data from Service Now:

[image]

Parse JSON and Initialize Array Variable to store final output:

[image]

For Each loop to change JSON body for each record, and then Append each record to an Array Variable:

[image]

[image]

HTTP POST top upsert all (6213 records) data from the Variable to SAP:

[image]

And here's the limitation message from SAP when I run my Logic App:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code>BadRequestException</code><message lang="en-US">Upsert content exceeds the limitation, the maximum size is 1000</message></error>
```

...which is expected from SAP https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2615424

Can someone please advise how do I Upsert data in smaller amount from Logic App?

Comment: Hi Victor, I found there is a mistake in one of the screenshot of my answer. The expression of first screenshot in step 6 should be `take(variables('restProjects'), 1000)` but not `take(variables('restProjects'), 3)`. Take first 3 records is for test in my side.

Comment: And if still have any problem with the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so clear about SAP upsert, but if your requirement is separate `allProjects` to multiple collections(less than 1000 records) and then do upsert with each collection, you can refer to my logic app below:

**1.** I created a logic app with the actions below to simulate your `allProjects`(you do not need to care about the details of this step)
[image]

**2.** Then I initialize four variables.
[image]

**3.** Use a "If" condition to judge the size of `allProjects`.
[image]

**4.** If false, you can do upsert operation with `allProjects` directly. If true:
[image]
The whole expression of set `size` value is `add(div(length(variables('allProjects')), 1000), 1)`

**5.** Use "Until" loop, condition for exiting the loop is `size` equals to `0`
[image]

**6.**

The details of first two actions in "Until" shown as (do upsert operation in "HTTP" action):
[image]

The expression above should be `take(variables('restProjects'), 1000)` instead of `take(variables('restProjects'), 3)`. Take first 3 records is for test.

The details of next three actions in "Until" shown as:
[image]